# Using Service as singleton in Android

Tags: android, design-patterns, singleton, android-service, android-lifecycle

Is it a bad practice to create a `Service` that works as a singleton? I mean a `Service` that is never stopped and that contains some private data that some other engines and `Activities` would use, so the `Service` could have something like:

```
public class CustomService extends Service {
    private List<Profile> mProfiles;
    private static CustomService instance;

     public static CustomService getInstance() {
         if(instance == null) {
             instance = new CustomService();
         }
         return instance;
     }

     public List<Profile> getProfiles() {
          return mProfiles;
     }

     @Override
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
         ...
     }
     ...
}
```

The reason of doing a `Service` instead of just a singleton is that it must work independently of the application, as when it starts it connects a websocket that should never be closed and do not depend on the application. What would you suggest me to do? Is there a better way to re-use the `Service` in order to have some data (for instance the `mProfiles` array) available from other engines and `Activities`?

I've read somewhere that a `Service` works as a singleton, but I don't know how to access the private variables from any other point in application.

Comment: As far as I know you should not create a service instance yourself but should use `startService()` using a context. I'm not sure what the consequences are of using `new CustomService();`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But startService will start the service and call the onStartCommand, but this is not what I want. I want to start the service once, on the application's onCreate method, and then from any other point of the application get a private variable of the service

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is it a bad practice to create a service that works as a singleton?

It is redundant and, in the way you suggest, not going to work from the point of view of `Android` `Service` as application component which is to perform its functionality with respect to

- `Application` lifecycle that, in its turn, affected by
- system events.

Such an intention of an application component is reached by

- its declaration in the `AndroidManifest.xml`,
- triggering it (starting / binding / registering) and
- creating (by the system) an instance of the component within `Application` and "attaching" it to `ApplicationThread`/`ActivityThread`.

That said, brings to the fact that application components are tied to the `Application` instance hosted by OS process and **can't run independently**.

---

Regarding *your approach*, there are *two scenarios*:

**1.** **`CustomService`**'s default *constructor is private* as per the pattern.

By calling `getInstance()` a single instance of `CustomService` is created. The instance is just a `Java` object (singleton) that has nothing in common with `Android` `Service` application component. The `onStart()`, `onStartCommand()` etc. methods will never be called by the system.

An attempt to start the "service" (declared in the manifest) with [`startService(Intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)) will fail with `IllegalAccessException: access to constructor not allowed`.

**2.** **`CustomService`**'s default *constructor is public* (as per the code posted).

If the service is declared in `AndroidManifest` and the default constructor is empty, `startService()` won't fail, however `getInstance()` will create another instance of `CustomService` that won't be treated as `Android` `Service` application component.

This isn't a singleton.

---

> What would you suggest me to do? Is there a better way to re-use the service in order to have some data (for instance the mProfiles array) available from other engines and activities?

Use `Service` as per [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and pick the kind of communication you need:

- One-way communication (`Activity` `-->` `Service`) - use a [started `Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingStartedService) and handle each `Intent` (with your data attached to it, like `mProfiles` in case `Profile` class implements [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)) in `onStartCommand()`;
- Two-way communication (`Activity` `<->` `Service`) - use a [bound `Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) and communicate via `IBinder`.

Finally, `Service` in `Android` is a singleton. There is only one instance of each service in the system. It starts on demand and handles all pending `Intent`s / bound clients. Once it's done or explicitly stopped, it will be destroyed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But then, is there a way to get the private variables of a Service from an engine? I've read that only Activities or Services can bind to a Service so, how could I get the mProfiles array (for instance) from a broadcast receiver or from another singleton or engine? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Its bad practice to create a service as a singleton.You can start your service sticky and you can retrieve your service by its name and check if its working or not with the following code from inside an activity.

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If (and I haven't found documentation to support this but assume it's the case) the Service is instanciated only once by the Android framework, then you could initialize `instance` inside `Service.onCreate`. The only drawback being that you don't have a guarantee when this will be called. I.e., if you call startService inside `Application.onCreate`, you'll most likely have to wait a bit before your service is actually instanciated.