# Kotlin Intent with Service Class that requires a constructor

Tags: java, android, android-intent, kotlin, android-service

I am starting a service from a `Fragment` class. My `Service` class has one argument in its constructor.

From my `Fragment` I have a function that triggers this:

```
val serviceIntent = Intent(context, ServiceClass::class.java)
activity!!.startService(serviceIntent)
```

And this is my Service class, which uses a Singleton that requires a `Context`:

```
class ServiceClass(var context: Context): Service(){

companion object : SingletonHolder<ServiceClass, Context>(::ServiceClass)

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

     return START_STICKY
}
```

Every time I call my `Intent` I get an error:

> Unable to instantiate service ServiceClass: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class has no zero argument constructor
>           at ...

How would I come about passing a `Context` argument via an `Intent`

Any link to documentation on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Service is already a Context. There is zero reason to do this.

Comment: There's other components to this class that require me to use a Context. I've edited my question to include that requirement.

Comment: Then you can pass it `this`

Comment: If you need Context for _"other components to this class"_ pass the Service itself, cause Service is Context too, as @EpicPandaForce pointed out. Regarding creating own Android Services with "custom" constructors, [Using Service as singleton in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35024311/3290339) is worth to look at.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, this really helps me out, I'll review Service more thoroughly, not only is it a Context, but it seems to work similarly like a Singleton which would means I could remove my whole need for a Singleton as well.